# iOS 10 open app normal or with url

Tags: ios, swift, url

I'm creating an iPad app with a SplitViewController, thats supposed to work in 2 ways.

1. You just open the app, and are presented with a master tableview
   showing some assignments. These assignments can be 1 of three
   different types. You select an assignment and are presented with a
   detail ViewController using a show detail segue
2. You click a link
   from another app, opening the app with an id, and should now only be
   presented with the assignment corresponding to the id.

I have the following functions in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    splitViewController.delegate = self
    splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryOverlay
    return true
}


func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if let itemid = getQueryStringParameter(url: url.absoluteString, param: "itemid"){
        print(itemid)
        NetworkService().getSpecificExercise(id: itemid) { response, error in
            let exercise = response! as VoiceExercise
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            switch exercise.type {
            case "STRENGTH":
                print("Strength")
                let initialViewController : StrengthViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StrengthViewController") as! StrengthViewController
                initialViewController.exercise = exercise
                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            case "RANGE":
                print("Range")
                let initialViewController : RangeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RangeViewController") as! RangeViewController
                initialViewController.exercise = exercise
                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            case "COMBINED":
                print("combined")
                let initialViewController : CombinedViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CombinedViewController") as! CombinedViewController
                initialViewController.exercise = exercise
                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            default:
                print(exercise.type)
            }

        }
    }
    return true
}
```

My problem is, that if the app has not been started yet (ie not running in background), and I open the app from another app (or a test link on the same ipad through safari), nothing happens from the open url function - it just shows the splitviewcontroller, with the tableview, as if I'd opened the app on its' own.  If the app has already been opened, it behaves as expected - showing the assignment I expect.

Right now that is what I want. When you end an assignment, it opens the other app again, if the app has been opened by a link.
If I wanted to (when I click a link to open) show the assignment, but contained in a navigationcontroller, that was contained in the splitviewcontroller, where the splitviewcontroller had its' desiplaymode set to .primaryHidden, how would I go about this. All tutorials I've found only deals with Navigationcontroller, not contained in a splitviewcontroller. (this is still only for open url)

Comment: Please add your Info.plist, Apple requires you to specify the URL scheme you want to listen on in there.

Comment: Hi Jacob. I've already set that up. I have a URL Scheme called xxxvoicetrainer, and a URL Identifier. I've also set up a website, that has links in the form of: `<a href="xxxvoicetrainer://?itemid=1">Styrketest</a>` - all that is working. I think I've just not set it up correctly in appdelegate

Comment: It's possible that the method you are implementing was deprecated in Swift 3. Try this one `application(_ application: UIApplication, handleOpen url: URL) -> Bool`

Comment: My implementation _is_ the Swift 3 syntax